# Trying to grasp how to compute a $n$-step transition probability

Tags: markov-chains, transition-matrix

As the title suggests, I am trying to understand how to compute a $n$-step transition probability given a transition probability matrix.

Please understand that this is purely for me to prepare for an exam and not a homework question (It might be too trivial to be a homework question anyway).

Suppose we have simple transition probability matrix, P denoted by:

\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 2/3 & 1/3 \\
    1/2 & 0 & 1/2 \\
    1/2  & 1/2 & 0 &
  \end{bmatrix}
with three states, $X_{n}=\{0,1,2\}$. So, for example, $P_{01}$, which denotes the one step probability that a state at $0$ will be at state $1$ in the next step is $\frac{2}{3}$ as given in the matrix above.

My professor gave us a formula to calculate the $n$-step transition probability which is: $$P^{(n)}_{ij}=\sum_{l=0}^{\infty} P^{(m)}_{il}P^{(n-m)}_{lj}.$$

Suppose I want to calculate $P^{(3)}_{00}$ and say, $P^{(2)}_{23}$. How can I apply the formula to calculate the above probabilities?

I have also referred to: https://www.dartmouth.edu/~chance/teaching_aids/books_articles/probability_book/Chapter11.pdf
but it only had one numerical example of computing a 2-step transition probability. Can someone show me how to do it, step-by-step? Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: The formula you have is called the Chapman-Kolmogorov equation. It says that the probability of [going from state $i$ to state $j$ in $n$ steps] is the same as the sum over all states $l$ of the probability of [going from state $i$ to state $l$ in $m$ steps, then going from state $l$ to state $j$ in $n-m$ steps].

The Chapman-Kolmogorov equation is not useful for answering your question. To find $P^{(3)}_{00}$, just take the $(0,0)$ entry of the matrix $P^{3}$, the third power of the matrix $P$.

Comment: That is, the $n$-step transition probabilities are exactly the entries of the matrix $P^{n}$.

Comment: Hi @MarkPerlman, thanks for your response! So may I clarify that to find $P^{(2)}_{23}$ would be the same as the (2,3) entry of the $P^{2}$ matrix? Lastly, what if the transition probability matrix is huge, say $6x6 $. Wouldn't matrix multiplication be very cumbersome?

Comment: Your comment about $P^{(2)}_{23}$ is correct. Indeed, $P^{n}$ can be hard to compute by hand, but is very easy with a computer. If you have to do it by hand, diagonalizing $P$ first will make it easy to compute powers; then the only hard part is the diagonalizing.